# Как исправить систему проверки на касание к земле?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю 2д Платформер. Сделал такую систему проверки на прикосновение к земле:

```
public class GroundChecker : MonoBehaviour {

private Character player;
private void Start()
{
    player = GetComponentInParent<Character>();
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
   if ( collision.gameObject.layer==8)//8 слой-слой с объектами по которым можно ходить
   {
       player.onGround = true;
   }
}

private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.layer == 8)
    {
        player.onGround = true;
    }
}

private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)//Проблемный участок       
{
   if (collision.gameObject.layer==8)
   {
       player.onGround = false;
   }
}}
```

Земля у меня состоит из нескольких блоков.
Когда персонаж переходит с одного блока на другой на несколько мгновений играет анимация прыжка. Как изменить проверку на выход из "земли"?

Comment: добавить проверку на вертикальную скорость (==0)?

Comment: Используй возможности Physics2D, там столько функционала для разных ситуаций) Например 
Physics2D.IsTouchingLayers, можно проверить касается ли коллайдер какой-либо коллайдер на отдельном слое(слоях, задается маской)

Answer (score 0):

Персонаж висит у вас в воздухе, т.к. на момент OnTriggerExit2D вам не известно касаетесь ли вы сейчас какого-то другого коллайдера или нет, и вы всегда выставляете onGround = false.
Как вариант добавить int поле, которое будет держать в себе количество коллайдеров, с которыми вы соприкасаетесь. Т.е. при OnTriggerEnter2D увеличивать этот int на единицу, а при выходе уменьшать. После уменьшения проверять равно ли 0, и только если равно делать player.onGround = false;
Если проблема останется - значит между блоками земли слишком большое расстояние и между их коллайдерами есть зазор - уберите зазор сдвинув коллайдеры, либло блоки и проблема будет решена)
При этом OnTriggerStay2D вам, в принципе, не нужен :)